# Regular Expressions in Python-Scraping Data from website

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I trying to pull in xml files from a website and load them into a database. I have been using the Beautiful Soup module in Python but I cannot pull in the specific xml file that I want. 
In the website source code it looks as follows:

```
<a href="ReportName I want 20130101.XML">ReportName.XML</a>
<a href="ReportName I want 20120101.XML">ReportName.XML</a>
<<a href="ReportName I dont want 123.XML">ReportName.XML</a>
```

The following shows the code I have in Python. This brings back everything with the 'href' tag whereas I want to filter the files on the 'Report I want name dddddddd'. I have tried using regular expressions such as 'href=\s\w+' for example but to no avail as it returns NONE. Any help is appreciated

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

webpage=("http://www.example.com")
response=urllib.urlopen(webpage).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(response)



for link in soup.find_all('a'):
   print(link.get('href')
```

When I use Python it findall('href') it pulls back the entire string but I want to filter just the xml aspect. I have tried variations of the code such as findall('href\MarketReports') and findall('href\w+') put this returns "None" when I run the code.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example (such as the XML or an excerpt thereof), and more importantly the exact code you're using?

Comment: What exactly is the output you're looking for?

Comment: Also, unless I'm mistaken, `findAll("href")` wouldn't get you this tag, `findAll("a")` would.

Comment: I want to download an xml document from a website and upload it to my database

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear exactly what you're looking for, but if I understand correctly, you only want to get ReportName.XML, in which case it would be:

```
find('a').text
```

If you're looking for "/MarketRepoerts/ReportName.XML", then it would be:

```
find('a').attrs['href']
```

Comment: Well, then that's because the particular tag you've found doesn't have the `href` attribute.  `'href'` definitely _does_ work in the `attrs` dict.

Comment: Thanks jdotjdot, I am a trying to get my head around Python

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it was able to find the reports as I needed them. The Google presentation was a great help along with jdotjdot input

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWyoYtvJpe4

The code that I used to find my XML was

```
import re
import urllib

webpage=("http://www.example.com")
response=urllib.urlopen(webpage).read()

print re.findall(r"Report I want\w+[.]XML",response)
```